# Motherboard B450 GAMING PRO CARBON AC (MS-7B85) showing red VGA light but GPU is not the issue

Tags: display, graphics-card, cpu, motherboard, hardware-rec

Built computer 2019, parts below, been working OK. After shutting down my computer, it refuses to give signal to the monitor. This has happened before but I usually just need to restart it 5-20 times and it magically works one of the times. This time however, I have restarted 300+ times and still no signal to monitor. All lights and all fans inside of the computer starts, but the motherboard continually displays a red color on VGA (ez debug).

The monitors and their cables work with another computer. I have checked every cable in my case, cleared CMOS battery in different ways 3+ times, picked computer apart and built it again 2 times (checking every component for damage). I have tested with another PSU, another graphics card and my RAM sticks in every configuration imaginable, still nothing. This leaves the CPU and motherboard. I highly suspect the motherboard since I did a bios update 2 weeks prior (to fix RAM compatibility issue). But everything has been working for those two weeks, except random closing / shutdown of a demanding game . I also stresstested every component for hours, and CPU, RAM, GPU, SSD all came out OK with very good temperatures.

**Questions:** Is there anything else I can do to fix it besides buying a new motherboard? Are MSI motherboards really that bad that it randomly breaks catastrophically after 4 years? Could the update of the BIOS cause this behavior? I have tried downgrading bios to previous version but when I press flashback button with USB-stick (fat32) with MSI.ROM file no light flashes so it does not seem initialized. Can I be relatively sure the motherboard is the culprit, or could the CPU cause these kinds of issues?

```
Processor: AMD Ryzen 5 2600X Six-Core Processor 3.60 GHz
Graphics card: Nvidia GeForce RTX 2060 6GB
Power supply: Corsair RM750X 750W v2
SSD: Crucial MX500 500GB 2.5"
RAM: Corsair 32GB (x8GB) DDR4 3000MHz CL15 Vengeance LPX
Motherboard: B450 GAMING PRO CARBON AC (MS-7B85)
```

Comment: Your issue of having to reboot 20 times to get your system to work isn’t normal. That most certainly points to a CPU or motherboard issue. Unfortunately both are equally likely

Comment: @Ramhound I mean yeah it shouldn't happen but if it happens once every 6 months and 99.9% of the time the computer works flawlessly I would not expect it to catastrophically fail like this.

Comment: Well you also have applications randomly closing.

Comment: @Ramhound Yeah fair, I guess you are right.